# grails plugin redis: ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I am trying to use grails cache-redis plugin.So I added this to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile ":redis:1.4.2"

compile ":cache-redis:1.0.0"
```

Then I added this to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.cache.config = {
    cache {
       name 'message'
    }
 }
```

and I used this method in one of the controllers:

```
@Cacheable('message')
def domainSubjects(){
    def subjects = Subject.findAll()
    def result=[]
    for(def subject:subjects){
        result.addAll(["id": subject.id, "name":subject.name, "description":subject.description])
    }
    render result as JSON
    return
}
```

In the controller file I imported these files:

```
import grails.plugin.cache.CacheEvict
import grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable
import grails.plugin.cache.CachePut
```

as nothing related to cache-redis plugin comes up in eclipse autocomplete.Now when I execute this method I get this error:

```
Class    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message  redis/clients/jedis/BinaryTransaction
```

I can not import this class,it gives compile error saying can not resolve class 
`grails.plugin.redis.clients.jedis.BinaryTransaction`.

The plugins are installed correctly,as I did `grails run-app` after adding compile dependencies.

How to resolve the error?Please help

Comment: Have you try running "grails refresh-depencies"?